# How to arrange three views horizontally?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I have three 3 `textview` in horizontal. 1st and 3rd `textview` is static mean its specific `width` but 2nd one is dynamic. when 2nd `textview` get more data then hide other `views`. To solve that i used `LinearLayout` .First give weight to all view but that create spacing problem between `view`.
Then i tried to  add `weight` to individual view then last view not showing.
`LinearLayout` is not Compulsory.
I want  Equal spacing between `views` and every view should be visible just like this.[image]

This is my code

```
          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"

                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ronald Flores long text xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxLength="120"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Thanks In Advance . I will Appreciate you Answers.

Comment: You want equal spaced textviews, right?

Comment: yes, equal spacing mean 5dp margin from left.

Comment: what exactly goes wrong when you don't use weights?

Comment: @IvoBeckers When 2nd `textview`  get big data it hide the 3rd `textview`.

Answer (score 1):

Is using a LinearLayout mandatory for you ? If not, you can try with a TableLayout and the system of weights, the result looks quite good to me.

Here is the XML code for using a TableLayout :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:gravity="center">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/table_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="tv1"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="tv2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="tv3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
```

Then, when you manipulate data and need to stretch your second textview, you can do it programmatically, for example :

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams;
layoutParams = (TableRow.LayoutParams)tv2.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = 4;
tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Below is the difference when the weight of the second textview is 2 before and 4 after :
[image]

[image]

If you don't want the first and third textview to be shrinked when the second stretches, you could try to play with the layout_span attribute of each view

I hope this helps, let us know if it works.

---- **UPDATE 1** ----

Apparently, using a RelativeLayout coupled to a maxLength restriction on your second textview can make it happen, you could try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="tv1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLength="@dimen/max_char_40"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Ronald Flores dfdfdfdfdbnbnbnnbnbnbffdddfdfddffdf"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tv2"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="tv3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what we obtain with a short text and then a long one on tv2 :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried this It is not working .Check question i have added output . `Programmatically` changing weight is  not good way .

Comment: Okay, so you said your tv1 and tv3 are static size. So a solution could be to add a new entry to your dimen.xml file for the max number of characters in your tv2, for each resolution you support. Then in your second Textview, add this line : android:maxLength="@dimen/maxChar20". You would first have to find the good limit for each resolution, but then your tv2 will never hide other views ! Try it out and let us know.

Comment: yes exactly. Currently i just used this technique  to solve the problem but this is NOT  proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ronald Flores"
            android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text14sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:maxLines="1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text14sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this technique work then there is `more  data ` but when there is less data it increase spacing between 2nd and 3rd `textview`

Comment: It works with any data, i have tried it personally and then sent it to you

Comment: You can give weightsum to linear layout as well

Comment: I'm also trying. When i give `weightsum ` then it works certain limit then it hide last view.

Comment: Yeah, please format your code first, by pressing ctrl+alt+l

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView  " />

<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this equal distribute space between `view` this not i want.